# How to prevent the default browser from generating a new session when my app launch it?

Tags: android, servlets

I use HttpUrlConnection to connect with the servlet, and the servlet return the sessionid to my app, then my app launch the default browser.Before the servlet return the sessionid, I set an attribute in the session.

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("ErrorInfo", "wrong!");
```

In the android app, it get the sessionid and launch the default browser.

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://192.168.1.100:8443/test/error.jsp;jsession=" + sessionid);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and in the error.jsp, it will get the attribute like this:

```
    <%=session.getAttribute("ErrorInfo") %>
    <%=session.getId() %>
```

when I test it, I thought it will show "wrong!",but the jsp page showed "null" and the browser generated a new session.the sessionid in the address bar is different from the value of session.getId().

For example, the url in the address bar is "https://192.168.1.100:8443/test/error.jsp;jsessionid=C4E6732EBB4C17F409AB41143735C096".

In this case, I think the browser shouldn't generate a new session, but it did.

OK, I have solved this problem by myself. The problem is caused by the browser. First, I use the browser to access the website, and the browser generate a session, then the browser will use this session until the browser is closed. So the sessionid delivered by my app will be ignored by the browser. To solve this problem, I let the app get the browser's session and use this session in the HttpUrlConnection, so there is only one session in the the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

May you try using '?' instead of ';' character in your URL while appending queryString part?

Comment: There is no need to try "?" because the problem is the "sessionid", the url-rewrite doesn't work because the browser already have a session with the website and the browser used the old session and ignores the id delivered by the app